# Any references for adsorption of ions to metal surfaces?

Tags: adsorption

I'm specifically interested in ions that would adsorb to gold surfaces, however I would be incredibly appreciative if someone could direct me to a textbook reference or something more expansive, that i could use to reference in the future.

I've been doing some reading and found the following regarding Silver:

*Silver Adsorbing*

Chloride, Bromide, Iodide, Urea, thiocyanate

*Silver Nonadsorbing*

Fluoride, Perchlorate, Sulfate

I know Gold leeches with cyanide and I think bisulfide.

 I actually found a good [set of lecture slides](http://www.fisica.unige.it/~rocca/Didattica/Surface%20Science%20and%20Nanostructuring/6%20adsorption%20at%20surfaces.pdf) that discusses chemisorption an Oxygen atom across a series of Transition metals. Also I'm also looking for something about physiorption not chemi...

 The slides reference a book called "Surface Science:Foundations of Catalysis and Nanoscience" by Kurt Kolasinski"...I guess I'll start there, but would love to hear about other references anyone else may have.

Comment: Almost all late transition metals adsorb $CO$ and isoelectronic particles, like organic isocyanides. Some of them (including gold) also adsorb sulfides and derivitives of S(-2), like alkylsulfides and ditiocarbamates, but the latter bonds very strongly (many catalysts are poisoned by tiny amount of sulfur in the feed). I tried to find a good book in the past, but found that there is not comprehensive systematic book, since the field only recently gained tools to be studied effectively. Your best bet is google scholar with subsecuent begging your scientific friends for help to get the articles.

Comment: Wish this was an answer so I could throw some points your way. I really appreciate it man! My position has moved me out of the ChemE field, so my current peers lack any chemistry at all. I'll have to go rub some old contacts shoulders. Thank you so much! And I'll let ya know if that book is actually any good. It's funny because the papers I have seen published in the 70-80's state that "X" adsorbs to Silver, but they never have any references. They all state whether these ions adsorb "specifically", regularly, or if they're non-adsorbing ions.

Comment: @permeakra You could flesh out your comment some more and it would be a very good answer!